# Java How to remove carriage return (HEX 0A) from String?

Tags: java, apache, chomp

If a particular String contains a newline character that is invisible (not \n but is 0A in hexadecimal because this value is passed down from the database), how can i able to chomp it away? Will Apache Chomp help?

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chomp(java.lang.String)

The hex form of the text returned from the database is "5761 6920 4D61 6E0D 0A"

It translates to "Wai Man" with a carriage return.

Comment: `\n` **is** U+000A (a.k.a newline). Could you tell us **exactly** what your `String` looks like? Best provide a `char`-for-`char` dump of it.

Comment: Hi joachi, it is returned as "5761 6920 4D61 6E0D 0A" for "Wai Man", a person's name.

Comment: This is simply "Wai Man" with a tailing `\r\n` (i.e. a DOS/Windows-style newline). `input.replace("[\r\n]+$", "")` should get rid of any tailing newlines on your input.

Comment: Joachim: I think that is a Unix newline..

Comment: No, [Unix uses a simple `\n` (a.k.a LF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression

```
String text = "Hello\r\nThere\r\n";
String shortText = text.replaceAll("\r", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked for me:

```
input_data.replaceAll("\\xC2"," ").replaceAll("\\xA0"," ")
```