# How to remove '0A' from string?

Tags: java, special-characters

I am trying to read a text file, line-by-line and concatenate the lines to create a single string. But while creating that unified string, `0A` is being added after each line. The string itself is just one line and I cannot see the `0A` in normal text/Java editor, but when I open it in an Hex editor, I can see '0A' after each line. I am working on a Linux (Ubuntu) platform.

I have tried every possible thing to remove them, specifically [Java How to remove carriage return (HEX 0A) from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870858/java-how-to-remove-carriage-return-hex-0a-from-string)

But I am not able to remove them. Any thoughts about how to do this?

**UPDATE:**

```
File workingFolderLocal = new File("src/test/resources/testdata");
String expected = "String1";

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.createPopFile(workingFolderLocal);

// Read the created file and compare with expected output
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(workingFolderLocal + "/output.xyz");
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
StringBuilder actual = new StringBuilder("");
String temp = "";
while ((temp = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
    String newTemp = temp.replaceAll("\r", "");
    actual.append(newTemp);
}
System.out.println("actual: " + actual.toString());
myInput.close();

Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Here is the output/error I am getting:

```
actual: String1
FAILED: testCreatPopFile
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<String1> but was:<String1>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:277)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:71)
```

Comment: The recipe in the other question should work. If it doesn't, please provide a small runnable test case demonstrating what exactly is not working for you and in what way.

Comment: If you use `BufferedReader.readLine()` they will be removed for you.  How are you reading the file?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Reading it with `BufferedReader.readLine()` only.

Comment: @NPE: I can post the code snippet, but I think there is no way to post the input file, which I think is the most important thing here. :(

Comment: Added code snippets, hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense and neither does your question. After readLine() there won't be any line terminators in the string.

Comment: In the assert, do you need to use actual.toString since its a stringbuilder?

Comment: Try printing `System.out.println("actual: " + Arrays.toString(actual.getBytes("UTF-8")));` I suspect your special character is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Mike: If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it. Such a silly mistake. Others, thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @Bhushan added my comment as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assert, do you need to use actual.toString since its a stringbuilder?

Added this from the comments in order to accept the answer.

@oheyder stumbled upon this as well.  Gave him a +1.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the `expected` variable is `String` while the type of the `actual` variable is `StringBuilder`. These objects will never be equal in the sence of ...

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

, because they have different types.

Answer (score 1):

The '0A' is the newline character ("\n").
You are only removing the carriage return character ("\r") (0D).
Try replacing "\n" as well in the same way you are replacing "\r".
As someone commented, the readline() call should take care of that though.

In windows, lines end with both \r\n
In *nix lines en only with \n

See [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)